GSM/GPS Performance difference between a vehicle tracker and mobile phone
I have used a vehicle tracking device (details attached below) and I have noticed something strange. I am actually comparing a mobile phone with a vehicle tracking device as both have GSM (SIM cards) and GPS modules installed in them.

The first thing is that if I pass by a jail where jammers are deployed, the GSM on mobile phone works (although poorly), but the tracker device goes offline, even though both devices are using the SIM card of the same provider.
While travelling in grey areas where mobile network is totally unavailable, both mobile phone and tracker won't work and that is understandable. However, while exiting that grey area, mobile phone will always register the SIM card back but the tracker won't do it always. It sometimes keeps offline and I have to inform this to the Telecommunication company. I do not know what they do but the tracker again gets online.

Are the issues in tracker devices because of poor GSM modules in them? The GPS performance of trackers is also not perfect as compared to a mobile phone. Sometimes, the tracker will show that your car is 100 meters away. But in reality, the car is just 10 meters away.
Country: Pakistan
Tracker: VG-03


Different cellular devices are built differently, have different components and different margins for noise.
So, one working less well than the other: totally expected.
The second thing with not re-registering, however, sounds like a plain firmware bug in the tracker.
